# How to move document.ready to js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have done jquery code in an aspx page. Now I want to move the code to Report-Filter.js file. I tried to move and execute. But it doesn't work.

This is my code;

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/Report-Filter.js"></script>      -------> // code

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="css/ReportsSalesAll-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/Accordian-Hide-Show.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/Accordian-Hide-Show.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Moved code to Report-Filter.js file
    })
</script>
```

But I didn't get the output. What I did wrong in my code.

Comment: `But I didn't get the output.`, what output? as of the code you pasted here nothing will happen.

Comment: Have you used `$(document).ready(function () {..
            })` in file?

Comment: @Satpal No I didn't use `$(document).ready(function () {.. })` in file

Comment: That's your problem then. You still need to include that in the JS of the external file

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes. Now it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write script tags in `.js` file remove script tags from `js` file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Moved code to Report-Filter.js file
    })
</script>
```

Should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Moved code to Report-Filter.js file
})
```

Also it would be better to place the `link` of file just before `close` of `body tag`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I'm going to assume some things.

What I think you need is

- Create a new file and put the javascript code in there with respects
  to what Leopard says.
- Reference your new javascript file in your code as shown in your
  question. Be sure to reference this AFTER you reference the JQuery
  libraries.
- Test your code. For example, by putting an alert in your Javascript
  file somewhere. Like this: alert("test");

Some general tips:

- Always put the CSS references before the JS references (Preferably in
  the head of the document). This way the page won't stutter visually
  while loading, because the elements put on the screen will already be
  styled.
- Always put the scripts you are referencing below your HTML elements.
  This way the page won't take too long to display, because the scripts
  won't load beforehand, but afterwards (which is correct anyway,
  because your code run's after the document has finished loading)

Eventually it should look something like this:

Javascript file (js/new-javascript-file.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("test");
})
```

Html / CSHtml / Aspx file (not sure what you are using):

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/ReportsSalesAll-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/Accordian-Hide-Show.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/Report-Filter.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="js/Accordian-Hide-Show.js"></script>
<script src="js/new-javascript-file.js"></script>
```